# Edit most recent message in Slack via key shortcut

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, slack

This concerns the Slack app (on Mac).
One common problem is that I need to edit the last message I wrote myself because it contained some kind of type. Is it possible to do this with a key shortcut or without using the mouse?

Since I am on Mac BetterTouchTool is available to automate multiple steps if required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the message box is selected (and empty), pressing the <kbd>↑</kbd> key will select your last message for editing.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks a lot. This will save me a ton of time.

Comment: @plttn do you happen to know where this message history is stored? I can't seem to find it. Thx